# How to add element to hashmap of Object,List<Object>

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a list from dao, I want to put this list in a HashMap>, my list can contain a service which have multiple parameters like the serviceId=3. In my final HashMap, the result looks like : `{Service 1=[100,A],Service  2=[101,A],Service  3=[Parameter[102,B],Parameter[103,B],Parameter[104,C]]}`.

```
serviceId   paramId   type
 1            100      A
 2            101      A
 3            102      B
 3            103      B
 3            104      C
```

Service.java

```
private int id;
//Getters+Setters
```

Parameter.java

```
private int id;
private String type;
//Getters+Setters
```

Test.java

```
 List result = dao.getServiceParam();
HashMap<Service,List<Parameter>> mapList = new HashMap<Service, List<Parameter>>();   
if(!result.isEmpty()) {             
for (int i=0; i< result.size(); i++) {
    Object[] line = (Object[])result.get(i);        
    if ((BigDecimal) line[0]!=null) {

    }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((BigDecimal) line[0]!=null && line.length>2) {

    Service serv = new Service((Integer) line[0]);
    Parameter param = new Parameter((Integer)line[1],(String) line[2]);
    List<Parameter> paramList=mapList.get(serv);
    if (paramList==null){
        paramList = new LinkedList<Parameter>();
    }

    paramList.add(param);

    mapList.put(serv, paramList);
}
```

You can replace your empty if with the code above.
This should serve your purpose I believe. but to run the above code you should meet below conditions.

1. your Parameter and Service class should have a constructor.
2. you should have overridden the hashcode and equals methods based on id attribute of Service class
3. If you expect null at any of the field. Please handle that.